# Ending with too many objects (layered design)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, solid-principles

I have a lot of dropdown lists, custom grids on my webform which are displayed to the end user. Each is populated from database through a DAL. I have separate classes defined for each.  However, I am thinking about reducing the number of classes, as every new requirement results in a separate custom object.

How can I reduce the no. of classes for such requirements? Should I use datasets, lists etc. ?

Comment: Do you have seprate classes for populating your model object or is it seprate model objects like (Person , Address etc)

Comment: I have separate classes for each domain object (tables). However, these custom classes I am ending up (dropdown lists, custom grids, lists) etc. which are not linked to a single table are growing. Currently I define these inside a separate namespace but I want to know how to handle this sort of scenario in an efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Separate classes defined for each" and "How can I reduce the no. of classes for such requirements".

Do you really create a new class for each dropdown list?
From my experience, usually I generalized it by using this class:

```
public class DropDownItem<T>{
  public string Display{get;set;}
  public T Value{get;set;}
}
```

It can be done using `Dictionary<T>` though.

Never used in ASP.Net, but it works well in Winform and WPF databinding. In Asp.Net specific, I think normal select-option is enough to supply the need.

However for gridview, you need to generalize your classes to be more generic. Declare a class which has most of the parameter, which is nullable.

Example one request has 10 parameter, 5 is mandatory and other 5 is nullable. Grid A display param 1,2,3,4,5,7,8 and grid B display param 1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10. This way, you can use one class in many more grid.

Don't use DataSets/DataTable. It is better to use more class than DataSet. The maintainability will be better when using more class than DataSet, because it is strongly typed, rather than "COLUMN_NAME" in DataSet.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this doesn't sound too critical, but if each requirement being added as a class is ending up as a lot work, perhaps you can look into inheritance to clean up boilerplate/shared code in those classes.

Generally a lot of small classes (that don't overlap functionality with other classes) is a good thing. The opposite complexity problem, the "god" class, where all your code is stuffed into fewer classes, is much worse.

Comment: thanks for your response. Some of my classes are just business requirements & used for only display purpose (say a grid made up of multiple tables). I Try to inherit where possible but I was just skeptical about the no. of classes I am ending up.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much unless you find yourself repeating yourself a lot. If you are not, you are most of the way there to great OO.